# How to handle CTRL-V in Excel VBA/Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA-macro which kicks in, every time a single value is entered into a cell of column A (Workbook_SheetChange).

Some users are pasting multiple cells or a entire line or multiples entire lines into the sheet to make it easier for them (CTRL-V).

If entire line/lines are pasted the macro is failing, sometimes the whole VBA_engine is broken and the user needs to restart Excel.

I would like to handle pastes (CTRL-V) in the manner of to disable the VBA-code after pressing CTRL-V but before content is pasted into the cells. Afterwards the VBA-code shall be started.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please [edit] and add the code of your `SelectionChange` event? Probably there is a way to fix it so it can handle Ctrl+V actions, so you don't run into errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the person who wrote the `Worksheet_Change` event did not make it handle changes from multiple cells. Either rewrite it or make sure to exit the event, whenever more than one cell is selected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'rest of the code here

End Sub
```

Comment: This will safe the macro from failing, but will not prevent pasting data.

Comment: @EganWolf To prevent pasting data you could just undo: `Application.Undo` before `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @EganWolf - the question is whether the OP needs to prevent the pasting of the data. The way I read it, I get the impression that the biggest problem is the "breaking of the VBA engine" (which probably means getting an error in VBA).

Comment: @Vityata I believe that this macro is important and it should run, so stoping it completely is not an option. Your're right that we need more info on this.

Comment: If you want a good answer you should ask a good question (include the failing code).